# SQLite queries to create a defined Java Object

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a SQLite table of this tipe

Table *Vehicles*:

```
CATEGORY    COUNTRY   ID    NAME          EMAIL
A           GE         1    BMW           sample1@salple.it
A           GE         2    Lamborghini   sample2@salple.it
B           GE         3    BMW           sample3@salple.it
```

I want to select all the entries that have a specified name or a specified category and pass all the parameters how each row in a constructor

```
Vehicle(String category, String country, int id, String name, String email)
```

I have implemented this adapter using some tutorials:

```
public class TestAdapter  
{ 
    protected static final String TAG = "DataAdapter"; 

    private final Context mContext; 
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb; 
    private DataBaseHelper mDbHelper; 

    public TestAdapter(Context context)  
    { 
        this.mContext = context; 
        mDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(mContext); 
    } 

    public TestAdapter createDatabase() throws SQLException  
    { 
        try  
        { 
            mDbHelper.createDataBase(); 
        }  
        catch (IOException mIOException)  
        { 
            Log.e(TAG, mIOException.toString() + "  UnableToCreateDatabase"); 
            throw new Error("UnableToCreateDatabase"); 
        } 
        return this; 
    } 

    public TestAdapter open() throws SQLException  
    { 
        try  
        { 
            mDbHelper.openDataBase(); 
            mDbHelper.close(); 
            mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase(); 
        }  
        catch (SQLException mSQLException)  
        { 
            Log.e(TAG, "open >>"+ mSQLException.toString()); 
            throw mSQLException; 
        } 
        return this; 
    } 

    public void close()  
    { 
        mDbHelper.close(); 
    } 



    public boolean SaveVehicles(String category , String country, String id, String name, String email) 
    {
        try
        {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put("Category", category);
            cv.put("Country", country);
            cv.put("id", id);
            cv.put("Name", name);
            cv.put("Email", email);

            mDb.insert("Vehicles", null, cv);

            Log.d("SaveVehicles", "informationsaved");
            return true;

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.d("SaveVehicles", ex.toString());
            return false;
        }
    }


}
```

But I don't know how I could implement the various get methods that I need, to meet a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating an object from a SQL query would look something like this

```
/**
 * @return Returns a list of all objects.
 */
public ArrayList<Object> getAllObjects() 
{
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE";
    // Get the isntance of the database
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    //get the cursor you're going to use
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    //this is optional - if you want to return one object
    //you don't need a list
    ArrayList<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<Object>();

    //you should always use the try catch statement incase
    //something goes wrong when trying to read the data
    try
    {           
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                 //the .getString(int x) method of the cursor returns the column
                 //of the table your query returned
                Object object= new Object(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                                        Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)),
                                        Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)),
                                        cursor.getString(3),
                                        cursor.getString(4),
                                        cursor.getString(5),
                                        Boolean.parseBoolean(cursor.getString(6))
                                        );                                      
                // Adding contact to list
                objectList.add(object);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    catch (SQLiteException e)
    {
        Log.d("SQL Error", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
      //release all your resources
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
    }
    return objectList;      
}
```

The code above assumes you have some table in your database named "SOME_TABLE" and that you have an object that takes 7 parameters but you should be able to alter the snippet to make it work for you.

Comment: The line 'SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();' show me an error... the method getWritableDatabase() is missing.

Comment: My apologies, you'll have to use new SQLiteOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase(); The snippet of code I provided was from something I wrote which extended SQLiteOpenHelper.

Comment: It would be nice if there were some convenience method for doing this when working with 50+ columns.

Answer (score 0):

You need to query your database for the data, and then iterate through the returned cursor to pull out the data you need and put it into strings to feed into your constructor.

The query would look something like this (using the info you provided and the `query` method):

```
public Cursor fetchList(String category) {
    return mDb.query("Vehicles", new String[] { "CATEGORY", "COUNTRY", "ID", "NAME", "EMAIL" }, "Category =" + category,
            null, null, null, null);
}
```

Note that this is a basic query and subject to SQL injection attacks,  It should be parameterized to make it less vulnerable, unless you are not going to allow the user to type in the category and rather have them pick from a list you provide.

Anyway, that would return your data in a cursor, with one row for each record that matched the search parameters.  From there, you would need to iterate through the returned cursor and pull the data out of it and into strings you can use.

Comment: could you give me more info? Thanks

Comment: for example, the Cursor returned from your query in that way should be converted in a list of Vehicle objects?